# AppEngine: Python 3 Version of Search API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Our service is evaluating steps to upgrade from python 2.7 to python 3.7. We heavily use document search [api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search), but I cannot find any similar api for python 3.

Is there a plan to support document search api in python 3? or any available alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Environment: appengine, python 2.7, standard environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host any full-text search database such as Elasticsearch on Compute Engine and access it from your service.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrating-services